# Alternative to Snappy from ESA to work in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, geocoding, software-recommendations, sentinel-1

Is there a Alternative Python Package (https://senbox.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SNAP/pages/19300362/How+to+use+the+SNAP+API+from+Python), which allows the User to geocode Sentinel-1 Data?

Snappy doesn't work when i try to install it to the QGIS-Python Interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an Alternative for Snappy i found pyroSAR, which works identical to snapista. It's super easy to install with pip and also uses the SNAP gpt.

https://pyrosar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your installation via the QGIS python interpreter fails could be that there is another package called snappy (https://pypi.org/project/snappy/) which is used when you use pip for example. Sometimes it is already installed with QGIS which causes additional problems.
It works when you use the full path to the QGIS python.exe in the command line as described in the ESA documentation you posted.

If you search for an alternative to snappy, you can use snapista. https://snap-contrib.github.io/snapista/
It is easy to use and directly calls the SNAP graph processing tool (gpt), so it's also computationally more efficient.

Comment: When i use the full Path to the QGIS python.exe i get an Error, that the "Python interpreter executable not found".

Comment: Can you please give an example how the full command looks like in your case? You can replace sensitive parts of the path (e.g. user directory) by ###

Comment: I found the Error for the missing intepreter, i forgot the Spaces in the File, my bad.
Now the problem is, that QGIS uses Python 3.9 and SNAP only works with Python 3.6, this is why i got an Error, so how could i create a virtual Environment in QGIS with Python 3.6?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot force QGIS to use another python version. Is it ultimately necessary to do the python processing from within QGIS? 
If so, the snapista package might be more suitable then.

Comment: it's necessary to do in QGIS because it should work inside a QGIS Plugin. Is there another way to Geocoding the Sentinel-1 Data (means: update the Orbit-Data, Radiometric Calibration, Orthocorrection and convert the DN-Values in dB-Values) in QGIS with Python?

Comment: As I said, you can install the snapista package I introduced above which allows you to start all these processing steps from within python (also inside QGIS). You define all steps (Read, Orbit File, Calibration, Range Doppler Terrain Correction, Conversion to dB) and they are handed over to the SNAP environment which processes them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the Hint @AndyB, the problem is, that the installation Guide of snapista is not viewable and the Github-Page doesn't exist anymore as it seems. So how can i install snapista with the OSGeo4W-Shell, so trhat i can use the snapisrta package?

Comment: You can read the documents directly from GitHub https://github.com/snap-contrib/snapista/tree/master/docs.

Comment: So no I'm trying to install Anaconda to use snapista in QGIS with the Python Console. I don't understand what's the workflow to install Anaconda for the use. Can anybody help me please? I normally only use OSGeo4W-Shell, so I sadly have no idea how to work with conda and how to manage it, that the Snapista-Package work in my QGIS Python Console.